# Make a Compound Control remove itself from parent Layout

Tags: android, user-controls

I created a Compound Control that is added at runtime from an activity, but will need to be removed when a button is clicked from within the control.

How do I send a message to the parent LinearLayout and tell it to remove the control? (Or tell it to remove itself - if that's even possible) If possible I'd like a method to do this from within the control itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Save reference of your control after creating, and use [ViewGroup.removeView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeView%28android.view.View%29) method when it is necessary.

If you need to do it from control itself, invoke ((ViewGroup)getParent()).removeView(this) from within the control.